# Would it be worthwhile to replace this OpAmp by a discrete amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, analog, noise

We have a circuit which works correctly with an OpAmp (as shown below) but we are considering replacing it with a discrete amplifier.

[image: opa838]

The gain we need is about 2200. The input signal comes from a resonant LC antenna (L ≈ 4mH, C ≈ 15nF, Rs ≈ 70 Ohms). The frequency of interest is 20 kHz with a 1kHz BW.

The noise generated is critical given the amplification. We would like the discrete amplifier to be as good or better than the [OPA838](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa838.pdf) in terms of noise, only in the band of interest, because we are doing digital filtering of the signal afterwards. This is why non linearities would not be that critical.

Our goals are the following :

- low power consumption (lower than the 1mA of the OPA838 @ 3.0V)
- amplification of x2200 at 20 kHz with 1kHz BW
- lower cost than OPA838
- gain error < +-20%
- output impedance < 10kOhm AC coupled
- input impedance should be high enough in order not to decrease Q

Given the small BW of the signal, and the low center frequency, do you think it is worthwhile (knowing our goals) to replace the OpAmp? If so, which transistors types and which topology would you use? We have everything at hand to simulate and then test in the real world.

Comment: There's a good reason that developing analog ICs is an expensive and highly specialised task. Not to say you _couldn't_, but you would have to justify the (considerable) amount of work that it would take...

Comment: Why have you chosen such a low Q (0.136) RCL circuit?

Comment: The OPA838 is a 300MHz GBW part; from a quick calculation you need a minimum of just over 4MHz (assuming a standard 20dB / decade roll-off) and a slew rate of around 500mV / uS. I assume you are talking about the amplifier quiescent current in the question (that is in the datasheet). There are numerous IC amplifiers that might meet your needs but you need to be careful of input offset voltage.

Comment: *The gain we need is about 2200* As an experienced engineer that makes me want to use **two** opamps, not one. Yes it can (theoretically) be done with one opamp but there will be many challenges. Making 2 times 47x gain will make a designer's life much more easy. My bet is that my 2-opamp design can beat your 1-opamp design in price and performance (price since I can use a much cheaper opamp).

Comment: There are plenty of dual amplifiers with a *combined* Iq of around 0.5mA at a lower cost than the OPA838. I strongly doubt you could get the performance from a discrete solution at that current and such a solution would very probably cost more. I looked around for perhaps 5 minutes and saw a number of potential parts.

Comment: @PeterSmith *I strongly doubt...* Well, I am **completely convinced** that what you say is correct. As an IC designer I know almost all the tricks that can be used on an IC which allows us to make such "good" opamps. Many of these tricks work poorly or not at all with discrete components. Would there be so many different types of opamps if it was easy / beneficial to build your own using discrete components? I think not.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie *Strongly doubt* is my way of saying "you could well be on a hiding to nothing" but prove me wrong if you can :)

Comment: +1 for spreading the gain over two stages. It will be much easier to keep things stable and get accurate amplification. First stage is basically an impedance converter that also has enough gain to make the second stage trivial to design.

Comment: For a single stage, the minimum effective GBW is 44MHz, not 4MHz. Indeed, if we split the amplifier into 2 stages, with identical 47x gains, we need only 1MHz GBW, so TSV522 could be a good candidate. But what about noise? OPA838 is quite good on this point...

Comment: It's fairly low noise, at half the noise of the NE5534. Can certainly be beaten with discretes, or a discrete front end to an opamp. but not at 1 mA current. 10mA maybe. Stick with what you have.